# Twitter 2.0 bootstrap navbar center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to center the navbar similar to how twitter.com or facebook does this.  Right now it looks like the navbar is stuck on left alignment.

Anyone have this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an image or screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid span12">
          <div class="navbar-text pull-left"><a href="/."><img src="/public/images/logo.png"/></a></div>
...

See, the "container-fluid" div seems to get left aligned on a larger screen.

@AndresIlich

Comment: Why not just use a fixed container instead? Fluid containers were meant to expand with your screen. Or you want your menu elements to be able to center on the screen automatically?

Comment: @AndresIlich This finally worked for me (stupid).  Please put an answer in the bottom so I could at least acknowledge your prompt and accurate responses!  Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking from the comments, using a `.container-fluid` container creates the undesired effect of the navbar being stretched, this can be avoided by replacing it with a `.container` fixed container instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced the examples Twitter Bootstrap provides to ensure you are structuring your HTML correctly? The navbar should extend the entire length of the window if implemented properly.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples

Comment: Perhaps I should start from scratch, but last night it didn't work out.  

I am able to have it extend the entire length of the window, but i'd like to keep it restricted to the inner div being "span12" class (940px or 960px width) and centered.

Comment: link is dead. Now: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples